# Detecting precise changes in Android phone tilt, rotation etc. for augmented reality type applications

Tags: android, motion-detection

Are there specific functions for accessing precise changes in an Android phone's tilt, orientation, elevation etc. for use in augmented reality type applications?

I'm looking for things like 0-360 degree values for tilt, same for horizontal orientation, and possibly elevation values in metres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For augment reality applications there is a library which is called as [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/). However while using ARCore, as far as i know it takes full control of the sensors like gyroscope in current version 1.4.0 . If you are not gonna use ARCore you can look to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview). You can see that there are lots of sensors but different devices have different sensors. Also another note that for elevation you can use [barometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_PRESSURE) or gps but they may not be so accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I won't be using ARCore, so I will check out the documentation you have linked me to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SensorManager will help. I used this manual [link](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out later.